# Difference between Host and Domain in Cookie parameters PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Suppose I have two session cookies which looks like

First one

```
Name: d58ba4091c622661a0d46f03b412ac8b
Content: m9ciub2u3ig59638r43uqjb8e6
Host: www.example.com
Path: /
Send for: Any type of connection
Expires:Sunday, February 27, 2011 5:50:18 PM
```

and second one

```
Name: test
Content: kdfssdfb2ufdfjww3436detasd
Domain: .www.example.com
Path: /
Send for: Any type of connection
Expires:Sunday, February 27, 2011 5:50:18 PM
```

If you can see first one contain `Host parameter` and value and second one contain the `Domain` parameter. 
What is exact they do and what's the difference b/w them?

Thanks

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setDomain($domain)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L117) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie). This handles some normalization efforts for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to comments to [setcookie() function description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), the difference is the following:

- Host: www.example.com

is restricted to specified host, so this cookie will not be visible neither to entirely different domains, nor to subdomains. Such cookie is created if setcookie() parameter $domain is set to empty string:

```
setcookie($name, $value, time()+3600, $path, "");
```

- Domain: .www.example.com

is restricted to specified domain, so this cookie will be visible to subdomains of specified domain (all domains like *.www.example.com). Such cookie is created if setcookie() parameter $domain is set to some domain:

```
setcookie($name, $value, time()+3600, $path, "www.example.com");
```